# Update data from one table to another failing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in two systems both have the same structure. I want update the data in one table to other

```
update Table1
set VIEW_CD = cmn.VIEW_CD,
    VIEW_DETAIL = cmn.VIEW_DETAIL 
FROM dbo.Table1 tbl
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 cmn ON tbl.id = cmn.id
```

Both the  columns in both the tables are null columns but I am ending up with the exception

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you have `NOT NULL` constraint on `Table1` , you should drop it :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ALTER COLUMN VIEW_CD <columnType> NULL
```

Or this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ALTER VIEW_CD DROP NOT NULL
```

And then run the query once again.

Comment: I tried the above alter statements but it still failed. The reason for "Cannot insert the value NULL into column column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." In my scenario the error was due to a trigger which was getting fired before the update statement is getting executed

Comment: @user3595236 Do it on the second column `VIEW_DETIAL` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
update Table1
    set     VIEW_CD = cmn.VIEW_CD,
    VIEW_DETAIL = cmn.VIEW_DETAIL 
    FROM dbo.Table1 tbl
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 cmn ON tbl.id = cmn.id
where VIEW_CD  IS NOT NULL AND VIEW_DETAIL IS NOT NULL
```

The above will update Table1 with all the records from Table2 where the records doesn't contain any NULL values.